# Using JGrowl with jQuery Validate error messages

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery Validate (http://jqueryvalidation.org/) for my client side validation

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $().ready(function() {
           //validate the inquiry form on keyup and submit
            $("#inquiryForm").validate({
                onkeyup: true,
                rules: {
                    fullName: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    inquiry: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 5,
                        maxlength: 500
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    fullName: $.growl({ title: "Growl", message: "Your name is required!" });
                }
            })
        })

</script>
```

(I am using server side as well, but because of the nature of the question it is not included here.)

This by default shows the error message below the input field. I want to use jquery Growl (http://ksylvest.github.io/jquery-growl/) for my error messages. I want an individual growl notification for each error message.

The jquery Growl looks like this:

```
$.growl({ title: "Growl", message: "The kitten is awake!" });
```

As you can see from the first block of code I tried adding it under the messages area of the validation script and now the growl message shows up when the page loads and then when you submit the form for validation, it just displays the error message below the field like normal.

Also, how would you have the validation script run on key up rather than on submit?

**UPDATE**

Based on requests here is the form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="inquiryForm">
   <div class="control-group">
     <label class="control-label" for="inputname">Your Name:</label>
     <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" name="fullName" id="inputname" placeholder="First and Last">
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="control-group">
     <label class="control-label" for="inputemail">Your Email:</label>
     <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="inputemail" placeholder="Email">
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="control-group">
     <label class="control-label" for="inputinquiry">Your Inquiry:</label>
     <div class="controls">
        <textarea name="inquiry" id="inputquiry" placeholder="Your Inquiry"></textarea>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="control-group">
     <div class="controls">
        <button type="submit" id="inquiryFormSubmit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Send</button>
     </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Remove line: `onkeyup: true`.  Why?  Because this is already the default behavior and setting it to `true` will break the plugin. [As per documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/):  _"Set to false to disable.  Set to a Function to decide for yourself when to run validation.  **A boolean true is not a valid value**."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `message` is the string you want to display. You can handle alternate presentations with `showErrors`. Add this to your `validate({})` call:

```
showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
     for (var error in errorMap) {
         $.growl({title: error, message: errorMap[error]});
     }
}
```

This will alert each error sending the fieldname as the title. You should be able to customize from there.

Comment: Ok this worked. But I don't like the title, I tried removing title: error, from the growl but now the title displays Undefined. How do I remove it all together?

Comment: Just pass the error string as the only argument: `$.growl(errorMap[error])`.

Comment: That results in both the title and the message being undefined. If i add `{message:(errorMap[error])};` it doesn't load at all.

Comment: I reviewed the plugin and showErrors is the correct answer. Thank you for the detailed explanation to my incorrect answer, it's been awhile since I used the plugin. I deleted my answer to prevent confusion.

Comment: Ok I put this in: `$.growl({message:errorMap[error]});` and it displays undefined for the title and displays the error for the error.

Comment: I was looking at the wrong plugin; just use an empty string for title, `title: ''`

Comment: I cannot believe that plugin defaults to `undefined` for a missing title.

Comment: Or set .growl-title {display:none} in your CSS

Comment: Looks like you can just use `$.growl.error({ message: errorMap[error] });` and not worry about the title

Answer (score 0):

**Quote OP**:

> *"Also, how would you have the validation script run on key up rather than on submit?"*

Remove this line:

```
onkeyup: true
```

Why? Because this is already the default behavior and [setting it to `true` will break it](http://jsfiddle.net/FhsTg/).

**`onkeyup:true` DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/FhsTg/ (broken)

**Working DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/FhsTg/1/

---

[As per documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/):

> **onkeyup**
> Type: Boolean or Function()
> Validate elements on keyup. As long as the field is not marked as invalid, nothing happens. Otherwise, all rules are checked on each key up event.
> - Set to `false` to disable.
> - Set to a Function to decide for yourself when to run validation.
> - **A boolean `true` is not a valid value**.

Comment: Well this solved the problem... Not sure if it's a good idea though. It displays another Growl every time you up on a key until the validation requirements are met.

Comment: @MitchEvans,  Your `onkeyup: true` setting broke the plugin.  However, if you don't want the `onkeyup` functionality, simply set it to `false`.